# prevent vue-cli (webpack) from picking up all non-file GET routes - sails environment

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, vue.js, sails.js

When creating a Vue project with `vue init webpack project-name`, setting it up, and finally calling `npm run dev` you can open your browser on `localhost:8080` and see the default page. In fact, you can navigate to mostly any "non-file" path, such as `/a/b/c-d`, and Vue will still pick it up. The only paths that it didn't seem to pick up are the ones ending with `.*`, and ones ending simply with `.`. Examples are `/a.js`, `/b.`, `/c/d.png`

I am trying to use Vue with a REST backend (Sails.js, using [sails-generate-new-webpack-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-new-webpack-vue)), which means I will have routes that will look like `GET /api/users` and similar. With that sails generator, a common webpack Vue project is generated, and some config files are changed in order to put the output of webpack onto the `.tmp` directory used by sails in order to actually serve files.

I tried looking at the source files and noticed that normally `npm run dev` calls `node build/dev-server.js`, as par `package.json`, but in there I don't see where it's actually redirecting everything to a single html file. That would already be helpful, but after a quick check I noticed that with my sails setup, that file is actually never used (plugged a simple `console.log` which never got ran).

How (or rather, where) does Vue redirect all "non-file" routes to a single path?

This may become clear as soon as I find out how and where it is, but otherwise, how do I change it and only make Vue pick up a specific express-route-like set of paths? As in, ideally I'd make it pick up routes such as `/:username/profile`

The answer doesn't have to be specific to sails, although if you have additional information, that might really help.

**EDIT: steps to recreate**

```
npm i -g sails sails-generate-new-webpack-vue vue-cli
echo "{\"generators\":{\"modules\":{\"new\":\"sails-generate-new-webpack-vue\"}}}" > .sailsrc
sails new test-project
```

**EDIT: turns out it's sails specific**

Turns out that what makes Vue pick every route is in `build/dev-server.js`, the history fallback API. That's great and I hope will help people looking for that answer, but with this specific setup, that file is never actually used, and I'm fairly clueless about what is being used. I do realize that there are very few people using the npm package I mentioned, but if anyone could give that a look, it would be extremely helpful!

**EDIT: found exactly where to deactivate it**

Had to look through a fair amount of source code, and saw `webpack/node_modules/sails-hook-webpack-vue/index.js`, just had to comment out lines 114 AND 120

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you don't need the extra server configurations provided by the **webpack** template.
I will advice you switch to **webpack-simple** template.

The dev server is located in the build folder, a file called **dev-server.js**. It uses express to setup a local server to serve your files.

If you setup your own server to serve the files, do remember to server the build*.js files.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got it :D

The issue was with [history-api-fallback middleware](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option), which is normally toggleable in `build/dev-server.js` on a normal Vue project.
But with my setup, it was ultimately being introduced in the local `webpack/node_modules/sails-hook-webpack-vue/index.js` on lines 114 and 120:

```
sails.config.http.middleware.historyFallback = historyFallback();
...
sails.config.http.middleware.order.unshift('historyFallback');
```

which you just need to comment out.

Then you can indicate your routes as you wish in `config/routes.js` and make them point to `index.html`